# Life imprisonment for Michael Burnham?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, michael-burnham

In Star Trek: Discovery, Michael Burnham was sentenced to life imprisonment. Given that she is serving on *Discovery*, does this mean that her crime is forgiven?

Comment: I'm making a rather substantial edit to clarify what I think is the meaning of your question. If I'm mistaken, please feel free to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 15):

Not at all. Burnham has not been pardoned. In fact, S1E5, "Choose Your Pain" makes it clear that she's basically been pressed into service under Star Fleet regulation 139.82, which allows conscription in a time of war. While she no longer seems to be confined to quarters when off duty (for example, nobody thought it was odd she attended the party in S1E7, "Magic To Make the Sanest Man Go Mad"), she still has no rank--strictly speaking she has to take orders even from Cadet Tilly right now. She has merely been remanded to the *Discovery*'s custody for the time being.

In S1E8, "Si Vis Pacem, Para Bellum", and S1E9, "Into the Forest I Go", Burnham makes it clear that she fully expects to be remanded back to prison when the war ends.

Comment: Pretty much agree. Though I'd also add that the Discovery is a top-secret ship, conducting fringe science experiments. Its existence is only known to its crew and a few very high-level Star Fleet people.  And probably Section 31. The captain of the Discovery has a lot of freedom to do (almost) anything he wants - including diverting one of the very best scientists from prison to serve under him.

Comment: For Burnham, practically speaking there's not much reason to be anywhere other than her cabin. Until the end of the 4th episode where Tilly implied that people's opinions on the ship were starting to change, what was she going to do outside her cabin other than work or eat? It's not as if people would be going out of their way to socialize with her.

Comment: I've updated my answer after "Choose Your Pain" made some things clearer, including the fact that Burnham's impressment is not a secret.

Comment: I've updated my answer again, this time to take int account events in E7 and E8, which further clarify her current status.

Comment: She refers to herself by the rank of "specialist" in places - which is kinda vague. Least in land militaries, it refers to mid-level enlisted personnel. Cadets are kinda considered almost officers so it makes sense Burnham 's lower ranked then here.

Comment: Star Fleet's use of enlisted ranks over the course of the various series is so muddled as to be an active perversity. The only unambiguous non-commissioned person we ever really get to know is Miles O'Brien, and it took several years to settle his status down to "Chief Petty Officer" while never really explaining how he's the only one we ever see. So in this context, I'm taking "specialist" to be a lot vaguer than the real military or naval use of the term.

Comment: There have been numerous occasions in prior Trek series where for whatever reason--an experiment, a particular mission--a "specialist" (even if not called that) has been brought aboard, often times civilian. It would make sense that she's been given that title, making it clear to the crew, especially those that might still have issues with her, that she's recognized as belonging on the ship, but at the same time she isn't officially in the chain of command. She'd also be expected to leave the ship once her particular reason for being aboard was over, in this case the war.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: As to your first comment, Burnham doesn't look like the social type _regardless_ of whether people want to socialize with her or not. But she is driven by her passions, so it stands to reason that she's always working (possibly on personal projects in her downtime). As to your second comment, Burnham's position is different than that of a guest or civilian. Burnham is still following hierarchy, whereas guests are accommodated and not put to work (specialists obviously work, but tend to work independently where possible and relevant).